# how to find the length of the text file which user uploads

Tags: php

Guide me to find the number of characters which are present in the text file which i upload.
This code will display the characters which are present in the .txt file`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>File Reader</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="file" size="60" accept=".txt" />
            <input type="submit" value="Show Contents" />
        </form>
        <?php
            if ($_FILES) {

                    $fileName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

                    $file = fopen($fileName, "r");

                    while (!feof($file)) {
                        echo fgets($file) . "";
                    }

                    while (!feof($file)) {
                        echo fgetc($file);
                    }
                    fclose($file);
                }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
$_FILES['userfile']['size']
```

this give you the size, in bytes, of the uploaded file.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: Actually i want to display how many characters and words my .text file has,

Comment: the size give you the size in bytes of your uploaded files for word  you should explode the file content by space  ..